# VPN Driver Failed, Cisco AnyConnect

Tags: windows-7, networking, drivers, vpn

I've been attempting to troubleshoot a VPN issue that I can't seem to resolve.

I'm currently using Cisco AnyConnect downloaded from the ASA.

I'm getting the following issue. I've tried a couple attempts from the interwebs, but I can't seem to figure this out.  I've changed the displayname in `regedit`, repaired VPN drivers and some other things.

Any idea on why I can't connect? (Other than the obvious driver error)

```
12:58:42 PM    User credentials entered.
 12:58:42 PM    Please respond to banner.
 12:58:44 PM    User accepted banner.
 12:58:44 PM    Establishing VPN session...
 12:58:44 PM    The AnyConnect Downloader is performing update checks...
 12:58:44 PM    Checking for profile updates...
 12:58:44 PM    Checking for product updates...
 12:58:44 PM    Checking for customization updates...
 12:58:44 PM    Performing any required updates...
 12:58:44 PM    The AnyConnect Downloader updates have been completed.
 12:58:49 PM    Establishing VPN session...
 12:58:49 PM    Establishing VPN - Initiating connection...
 12:58:50 PM    Establishing VPN - Examining system...
 12:58:50 PM    Establishing VPN - Activating VPN adapter...
 12:58:50 PM    Disconnect in progress, please wait...
 12:58:50 PM    The VPN client driver encountered an error.  Please restart your computer or device, then try again.
 12:58:50 PM    AnyConnect was not able to establish a connection to the specified secure gateway. Please try connecting again.
 12:58:54 PM    Ready to connect.
```

Answer (score 1):

Some things to check (in random order)

- In Windows Eventviewr (eventvwr.msc) check the "Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client" log.
  Since there seems to be a problem during, or right after "Activating VPN adapter" I would start by trying to find a corresponding eventlog entry and then check the subsequent ones.
- Try uninstalling and re-installing Anyconnect
- Are there any other security related tools installed (Norton, McAfee etc.)? If so try uninstalling them or disabling them as a test to see if they are interfering.
- [This Cisco troubleshooting note](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/100597-technote-anyconnect-00.html#anc37) suggests:

> In order to resolve this error, complete this procedure in order to
>   manually set the AnyConnect VPN agent to Interactive:
>
> Right-click My Computer > Manage > Services and Applications >
>   Services > and select the Cisco AnyConnect VPN Agent.
>
> Right-click Properties, then log on, and select Allow service to
>   interact with the desktop.
>
> This sets the registry Type value DWORD to 110 (default is 010) for
>   the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\vpnagent.

and

> When Routing and Remote Access Service (RRAS) is enabled on the Windows PC, AnyConnect fails with the The VPN client driver has encountered an error. error message. In order to resolve this issue, make sure that Routing and RRAS is disabled before starting AnyConnect. Refer to Cisco bug ID CSCsm54689 for more information.